# ElasticSearch - How to query a query from a dynamic field metadata?

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

ElasticSearch - How to query a query from a dynamic field metadata?

The metadata field is dynamic and there may be yes or no internal fields.

How can I return a query even though the "deleted" field is not defined in some of them?

Thanks for listening.

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "metadata",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should":[
                        {
                            "match":{
                                "metadata.deleted": true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "term": {
                    "on_behalf_of": "b71457f731d8a6f"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "[nested] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
                "line": 1,
                "col": 116
            }
        ],
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[nested] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line": 1,
        "col": 116
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is malformed. You are using two queries here `nested` and `bool`. Both these queries must be wrapped in either `must`, `should` or `filter` of a bool query. Assuming both the condition are necessary for a match, both these queries should be wrapped in either `must` or `filter` clause of a `bool` query as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "metadata",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "metadata.deleted": true
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "must": {
            "term": {
              "on_behalf_of": "b71457f731d8a6f"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```